# Bash on Windowsのダウンロードエラー(0x800703ee)

Tags: windows-10, wsl

現在Bash on Windowsを導入しようとしているのですが、コマンドプロンプトからダウンロードしようとした所、以下の様にエラー0x800703eeという結果が表示されてしまいました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

同様の失敗をした[情報](http://tooljp.com/qa/0x800703ee-Bash-on-Windows-error-9F54.html)を参考にFirewall設定の無効化をしてダウンロードしてみましたが失敗してしまいました。

Proxy経由では有りますが、設定は適切に出来ていると思うのですが、どなたか対処方法ご存知の方居ましたら教えて頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: Windows 10のビルド番号を追記していただけませんか？　スタートボタン→「設定」→「システム」→「バージョン情報」からご確認いただけます。

Comment: McAfeeなどののサードパーティ製アンチウイルスソフトが起動していませんか？

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありませんでした。ビルド番号ですが、手許のPCを確認した所、バージョン1607でした。アンチウイルスソフトに関しては、「ウイルスバスター Corp.クライアント」というソフトが入っている様ですが起動はしておりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

【注記】Windows 10 1709からWSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux)は正式となり、Bash on Ubuntu on WindowsはMicrosoft Storeから好きなディストリビューションを選んでダウンロードする形式に変更されました。質問の現象が発生するのは1703以下でのβ版WSLが対象であり、1703は2018年10月9日にサポートが終了するため、2018年10月9日以降は無意味な情報になります。(LTSBはそもそもβ版のWSLは使用できないようです。)

---

Bash on Ubuntu on WindowsのダウンロードはMicrosoft Store(旧名Windows Store)経由になります。つまり、Microsoft Storeからアプリがダウンロードできる環境でなければ、Bash on Ubuntu on Windowsもダウンロードできません。企業内であれば、ファイアウォールやプロキシでMicrosoft Storeへのアクセスを制限していないかを確認してください。特にBash on Ubuntu on Windowsはファイルサイズが大きいため、プロキシのウィルスチェックなどでタイムアウトが発生する可能性があります。プロキシ側でチェックを除外するなどの調整を行ってください。

プロキシやファイアウォールに問題が無い場合でも、クライアント側のサードパーティーセキュリティ製品(Symantec、TrendMicro、McAfee等の製品)が制限している場合があります。遮断ログが出ていないかの確認や一時的に無効にしてうまくいかないかを試してください。

ビルド番号によってはnetshでwinhttpを設定しなければならい可能性があります(Windows 8/8.1では必須でしたが、Windows 10でも必須かどうかは確定した情報は得られませんでした)。次のコマンドを管理者で実行してみてください。

```
netsh winhttp import proxy ie
```

最後に、Windows Updateでの0x800703eeというエラーコードはディスク容量不足で発生するようです。関連は不明ですが、Cドライブの空き容量をチェックをしてください。ディスク不良もありますので、イベントログでそのようなエラーが出ていないか、出ていればディスクチェックもしてみてください。

即座に思いつくような対処は以上になります。1703以下ではWSLはβ版ということもあり、多くの不具合がありました。ですので、まずは1709以降にアップデートすることをお勧めします。

Comment: 詳細な情報ありがとうございます。参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

コマンドプロンプトのプロパティの『従来のコンソールを使う』にチェックを入れてみては？
[Bash on Ubuntu on Windows Error: 0x80070002 WINDOWS Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/problems-reinstalling-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/bb32e0a5-e711-410b-b28b-ebc561d5b4d8?auth=1)

Comment: 質問に記載されたエラーコード0x800703eeとはエラーコードが異なりますし、エラーが出るまでの動作も異なるようですが、0x800703eeはこれと共通の問題ということでしょうか。